# How to add badge on a button in a cell?

Tags: ios

Achieve this without third party,
How to add a badge on a button in a cell?
Badgevalue change when receive a new message, and reset when pressed,

Comment: can I add a view like badge view on cell? Does any property or method ? How to initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`badgeValue` is a property of `UIBarButtonItem`, so you can simply set it with the following:

```
yourUIBarButtonItem.badgeValue = @"YourBadgeValue";
```

You can add this code to any method that is called when "reset" is pressed or anytime you want to change the value.